# discord.py - How to send a private message to a server owner?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make my bot dm the server owner whenever it joins a new server. I have tried this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
     user = await client.fetch_user(guild.owner)
     await client.send_message(user,"hi there!")
```

But it gives this error message:

```py
In user_id: Value "myname" is not snowflake
```

I can't figure out how to get the user id of the guild owner, i looked through the documentation but i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. You can just call the [`owner`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.owner) argument on a [`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild):

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    owner = guild.owner
    await owner.send("hi there!")
```